# Is there a way to debug the hierarchy when it's in the middle of integration test in Unity3D?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, integration-testing

Since when I run integration test in Unity 5.2.1 with Unity Test Tools, the screen would be locked up and if there's a fail case, I would like to know at that time that what's the hierarchy looked like to solve the problems. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could check the log http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: Not really what I want.